# how do select from table 1 based on table2 conditions

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables :

```
Teachers  : 
teacher_id
teacher_name
```

=============

```
Timetable:
tt_id
tt_teacher_id
tt_term_id
tt_day_id
tt_hour_id
```

### =====================================

I want 2 type **SQL** select query :

1)(this query for select teachers and set into combobox) select teachers_name that not exists in records with special parameters in timetable

```
tt_term_id=parameter1
tt_day_id  =parameter2
tt_hour_id=parameter3
```

### *teacher names comes from teachers table based on above conditions  in timetable table .*

2) select teachers_name that not exists in records with special parameters in timetable

```
tt_term_id=parameter1
tt_day_id  =parameter2
tt_hour_id=parameter3
tt_teacher_id !=parameter4
```

### teacher names comes from teachers table based on above conditions  in timetable table .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables based on the teacher id and use whatever conditions you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id, teacher_name
FROM Teachers
INNER JOIN Timetable
ON teacher_id = tt_teacher_id
WHERE tt_term_id = parameter1
AND tt_day_id  = parameter2
AND tt_hour_id = parameter3
ORDER BY teacher_name
```

The other one you will be able to come up with yourself :-)

If you want teachers who do not have any timetable records then you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id, teacher_name
FROM Teachers
LEFT JOIN Timetable
ON teacher_id = tt_teacher_id
WHERE tt_id is NULL
ORDER BY teacher_name
```